# SQL Server - splitting a value over several months without a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to split a value(X) over several months if it exceeds value(Y), without using a cursor?

For example, I have value X = 505 and I want to split it over as many months as possible with each month having a maximum value of 100 (value Y  = 100)?

So my expected output would be:

```
JAN    100
FEB    100
MAR    100
APR    100
MAY    100
JUN      5
```

I'm not concerned with the overlap (the 5 in June), if it were possible without this that is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a table of numbers to spread a value over a sequence of months using CROSS APPLY as follows.

```
create table T(
  id int,
  dat datetime,
  val int,
  primary key(id, dat)
);

insert into T values (1, '20140101', 100);
insert into T values (2, '20140101', 99);
insert into T values (3, '20140201', 274);
insert into T values (4, '20140301', 300);

declare @chunk int = 100;
select
  id,
  dateadd(month,n-1,dat) as dat,
  case when n=max(n) over (partition by id) then (val-1)%@chunk+1 else @chunk end as val
from T
cross apply (
  select n from Nums
  where n <= ceiling((val+@chunk-1)/@chunk)
) as N(n);
```

Result:

```
id  dat          val
1   2014-01-01   100
2   2014-01-01   99
3   2014-02-01   100
3   2014-03-01   100
3   2014-04-01   74
4   2014-03-01   100
4   2014-04-01   100
4   2014-05-01   100
```

(You’ll need to adjust things slightly if your values aren’t integers.)

Here’s some SQL to create a table of numbers from 1 to 1024 if you don’t have one handy.

```
create table Nums(
  n int primary key
)
insert into Nums values (1);
declare @i int = 10;
while @i>0 begin
  insert into Nums
    select max(n) over () + n
  from Nums;
  set @i -= 1;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the TOP X (rows) syntax?  If you are building the SQL query string you could use:

SELECT
   TOP  (505 / 100)
   *
FROM table

So that 505 / 100 rounds to an integer and you get only 5 rows.

Then you would need to join to a Calendar table to get the Months

Answer (score 0):

A little math can help, bit math.
Using the table from the answer of Steve Kass

```
declare @chunk int = 100;

WITH Base(N) AS (
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
), Base10(N) AS (
  SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) - 1
  FROM Base
), Counter(N) AS (
  SELECT u.N + 10*t.N
  FROM   Base10 u
         CROSS JOIN Base10 t
)
SELECT id
     , DateAdd(MONTH, N, dat) Month
     , Cast((val - (@chunk * N)) / @chunk as BIT) * @chunk
     + (1 - Cast((val - (@chunk * N)) / @chunk as BIT)) * (val % @chunk) Value
FROM   T
       LEFT JOIN Counter ON N < CEILING(Cast(val as Float) / @chunk)
```

The CTEs are here only to get a counter, the bit conversion is used as a IF, and can be translated to

```
IF (val - (100 * N) / 100) > 0 THEN
  RETURN 100
ELSE
  RETURN VAL % 100
END IF
```

The val column is casted to Float to prevent integer division, I used a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `CROSS JOIN` to be able to add the condition there instead of in a `WHERE` condition

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57f6c/2) demo, in the demo the chunk is static